# Polymer Dart @initMethod not executing

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I was fiddling with the "new" instructions for polymer dart 0.10.0-pre.10 only to realize I had package `0.9.5` installed (on an updated Dart Editor). And could only get code to run using `main() => dostuff();` Adding component1 as per [instructions](https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/pkg/polymer/CHANGELOG.md) just broke whatever worked.

I set `pubspec.yaml` polymer dependency to `>= 0.9.9` and it auto pub gets the version `0.10.0-pre.10`. Then I made changes as suggested and moved `dostuff()` to a custom element class (`extends PolymerElement`) and put `@initMethod` above it. It does not run.

And as I got it to run before I was unable to find a way to bind new items from a JSON file (which I successfuly got through http) to the polymer element.

mylist.dart

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';

@CustomTag('my-list')
class MyListElement extends PolymerElement {

  @observable List mylist = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

  @initMethod
  static dostuff() {
    print("initMethod");
    // get json and pass to mylist
  }
}
```

mylist.html

```dart
<polymer-element name="my-list">
  <template>
    <ul>
      <template repeat="{{item in mylist}}">
        <li>{{item}}</li>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart;component=1" src="mylist.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

index.html

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sample app</title>
    <link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="mylist.html">
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>MyList</h1>

    <div id="container1">
      <json-list id="my-list1"></json-list>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code (especially `@initMethod`) inside the element doesn't make sense.
`@CustomTag('my-list')` does this already. You need `@initMethod()` only when you want a method executed like `main()` that is outside of an Polymer element.

You can put this code inside the constructor of `MyListElement` or better inside `polymerCreated` before the super call.

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';

@CustomTag('my-list')
class MyListElement extends PolymerElement {

  @observable List mylist = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

  @override
  polymerCreated() {
    print("initMethod");
    // get json and pass to mylist
    super.polymerCreated();
  }
}
```

You didn't get Polymer `0.10.0-pre.10` because it is a pre-release which is indicated by the `-` after the patch version (not by `pre`).
Pub by default ignores pre-releases. You have to enforce them by a version constraint like `'>=0.10.0-'`

Comment: Ah, I see. I finally found in [this example](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-samples/blob/master/polymer_mini_samples/web/waiting_until_an_element_is_ready/my_element.dart) that I could put code inside a ready() function which would be executed, and now it renders the JSON in HTML. I suppose now you've mentioned it its better to put that in polymerCreated().
(@gunter-zochbauer BTW apologies for the duplicate posting)

Comment: Do you know how I can bind to the key/value pairs within a json object in polymer notation. i have template repeat="{{objects in jsonarray}}"... I want to lay out a table. say each object has {1: one, 2: two, 3: three}

Comment: This didn't work for a long time but I think I read that this was fixed recently (not sure though). If I remember correctly you should use it like "{{key in myList.keys}}" and when you need the value in markup you use "{{myList[key]}}". Please create a new question if it doesn't work and please accept my answer if it solves your problem (by clicking the checkmark below the up/down-vote buttons).

Comment: I didn't get that key/value binding to work . I posted it as [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450520/bind-json-key-value-pairs-to-table-template-in-polymer-dart). Checkmark for the answer to the OP.