# Bind JSON key value pairs to table template in polymer dart

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

how I can bind to the key/value pairs within a json object in polymer notation. i have template repeat="{{objects in jsonarray}}"... I want to lay out a table. say each object has {1: one, 2: two, 3: three}

something like:

```dart
<template repeat="{{item in mylist}}">
  <tr>
     <template repeat="{{key, value in item}}">
        <td>{{key}}: {{value}}</td>
     </template>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Comment: It helps to always add the `dart` tag because many people monitor just this tag.

Answer (score 3):

this code works for me:

**Dart:**

```dart
@observable List jsonlist = toObservable(JSON.decode('[{"1":"one"},{"2":"two"}]'));
```

**HTML:**

```dart
<template repeat="{{ foo in jsonlist }}">
  {{ foo }}
  <template repeat="{{ key in foo.keys }}">
    {{ key }} = {{ foo[key] }}
  </template>
</template>
```

With this code I get the following output:

> {1: one} 1 = one {2: two} 2 = two

Regards
Robert

Comment: This is basically the same as my code snippet. Thanks for trying out and posting the feedback. The difference is that you in addition change the JSON-Map to an observable Map. This is only necessary when you want to observe changes within the Map (add, remove, modify of items). If you just want to observe changes to the `jsonlist` field (assignment of another Map) the `@observable` annotation is sufficient.

Comment: Yes, sorry you're right. Thought you had a typo. But in the end this code works. Let's find out why alex is getting an error here.

Comment: No need to be sorry. I just wanted to highlight the difference. Another difference is that your code doesn't contain `<tr>`, `<td>`. Actually as far as I know this should be `<tr repeat="{{key in item.keys}}">` Some or all browsers don't allow the `<template>` as child of `<tr>`

Answer (score 1):

I think it should work this way:

```dart
<template repeat="{{item in mylist}}">
  <tr>
     <template repeat="{{key in item.keys}}">
        <td>{{key}}: {{item[key]}}</td>
     </template>
  </tr>
</template>
```

Please try and add a comment when it doesn't work (so I get a notification) then I build a demo app and try it myself.

Comment: I get error "Error evaluating expression '(key in item.keys)': Class 'JsonListElement'". I thought at first it was trying to use the bindings before it had time to fetch json from http. But then i tried declaring a simple json array in the class definition   @observable List jsonlist = JSON.decode('[{"1":"one"},{"2":"two"}]');
, but that didn't work either

Comment: Maybe this is a special case because you bind to a List of Maps. Can you try to bind to a Map first to verify if this works, using the binding syntax I explained in the comment below your previous question.
I'll try tomorrow. It's 1:00am and time for bed (yawn!)

Comment: I think your line (`@observable List jsonlist = JSON.decode('[{"1":"one"},{"2":"two"}]');`) should be `@observable List jsonlist = toObservable(JSON.decode('[{"1":"one"},{"2":"two"}]'));`.

What versions of Dart and Polymer are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working the way I wanted, which was to output a JSON array of JSON objects to a table, like this:

[image: jsontable]

jsontable.dart

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';

@CustomTag('json-table')
class jsontable extends PolymerElement {

   @observable List jsonarray = [{"id":1,"description":"cat"},{"id":2,"description":"dog"}, {"id":3,"description":"fairy"}];

   jsontable.created() : super.created() {}
}
```

jsontable.html

```dart
<polymer-element name="json-table">
  <template>
    <div>
      <table border="1">
        <tbody>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <template repeat="{{ key in jsonarray.first.keys }}">
                <th>{{key}}</th>
              </template>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <template repeat="{{ jsonobject in jsonarray }}">
            <tr>
                <template repeat="{{ value in jsonobject.values }}">
                  <td>{{value}}</td>
                </template>
            </tr>
          </template>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart;component=1" src="jsontable.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```